# Open the Safari app with URL in background without showing the Safari UI

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari

I want to open a URL from my current Cocoa app in Safari, but the thing is that I don't want the Safari UI to be visible to user. i.e. Safari should be executed in background without showing what is happening in it.
Is it possible ?

If yes please tell the method to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may open the URL in a web view by using `WebView` class and don't make the WebView visible to user if safari is not a compulsory requirement.

OR

You may use `Scripting Bridge` framework to minimize the application safari or use other methods in header file `Safari.h` to run it in background after opening the URL.
You may go through this [link](http://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/accesscontrol-scriptable-application-using-scripting-bridge-and-cocoa/) to know more about Scripting Bridge. For your task follow the steps below:

Generate a header file for safari, using the terminal command below:

```
   sdef /Applications/Safari.app | sdp -fh --basename Safari
```

Now, check your home folder or the current directory from which terminal cmd is executed to see a file `Safari.h`
Drag this file and add it to your project.
Add ScriptingBridge.Framework to your project.

Import headers:

`#import <ScriptingBridge/ScriptingBridge.h>`

`#import "Safari.h"`

Now use the below code to hide safari after opening the URL:

```
SafariApplication* sfApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];

SafariWindow* win =  [[sfApp windows]objectAtIndex:0];
[win setVisible:FALSE];
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, but I want it to be strictly on safari. Can you give example of second method of importing safari.h as I am new to cocoa.