# Open url in safari through cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari

I want to open a URL in Cocoa through my app in Safari only. I am using:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"my url"]];
```

But the problem is that if my default browser is not Safari, then the URL gets open in some other browser. But I want my URL to open in Safari only. Please tell the solution.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scripting bridge` with safari to open a URL in safari, You will find a method to open url in the file `Safari.h`.
To know more about using `Scripting bridge` refer the [link](http://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/accesscontrol-scriptable-application-using-scripting-bridge-and-cocoa/) and to use scripting bridge with safari and generate `Safari.h`, refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21721966/1987246) here.

The method to open a URL in Safari is:

```
NSDictionary *theProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"https://www.google.co.in/" forKey:@"URL"];
SafariDocument *doc = [[[sfApp classForScriptingClass:@"document"] alloc] initWithProperties:theProperties];
[[sfApp documents] addObject:doc];
[doc release];
```

Comment: Its apending file:/// while opening the url, therefore url not opening.

Comment: Yeah!! It's awesome!

Answer (score 14):

```
let url = URL(string:"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet")!
NSWorkspace.shared.open([url], 
                        withAppBundleIdentifier:"com.apple.Safari", 
                        options: [],
                        additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil,
                        launchIdentifiers: nil)
```

Comment: NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)

Answer (score 9):

Use [NSWorkspace's `openURLs(_:​withAppBundleIdentifier:​options:​additionalEventParamDescriptor:​launchIdentifiers:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:):

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://example.com")!
let browserBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.Safari"

NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURLs([url],
               withAppBundleIdentifier:browserBundleIdentifier,
                               options:nil,
        additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil,
                     launchIdentifiers:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use URL, you need a NSString

```
if(![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:fullPath
                            withApplication:@"Safari.app"])
    [self postStatusMessage:@"unable to open file"];
```

Answer (score -1):

To open a URL with any application, you can use the launch services. 
The function you want to look at is `LSOpenURLsWithRole` ;

**EDIT:**
You will have to link the SystemConfiguration framework to your project for this method to be available.

Apple doc reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenURLsWithRole)

For example if you want to open `http://www.google.com` with safari :

```
//the url
CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
//the application
NSString *fileString =  @"/Applications/Safari.app/";

//create an FSRef of the application
FSRef appFSURL;
OSStatus stat2=FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[fileString UTF8String], &appFSURL, NULL);
if (stat2<0) {
    NSLog(@"Something wrong: %d",stat2);
}


//create the application parameters structure
LSApplicationParameters appParam;
appParam.version = 0;       //should always be zero
appParam.flags = kLSLaunchDefaults; //use the default launch options
appParam.application = &appFSURL; //pass in the reference of applications FSRef

//More info on params below can be found in Launch Services reference
appParam.argv = NULL;
appParam.environment = NULL;
appParam.asyncLaunchRefCon = NULL; 
appParam.initialEvent = NULL;

//array of urls to be opened - in this case a single object array
CFArrayRef array = (__bridge CFArrayRef)[NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)url];

//open the url with the application
OSStatus stat = LSOpenURLsWithRole(array, kLSRolesAll, NULL, &appParam, NULL, 0);
//kLSRolesAll - the role with which the applicaiton is to be opened (kLSRolesAll accepts any)

if (stat<0) {
    NSLog(@"Something wrong: %d",stat);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

spawning a process and executing **open -a "Safari" http://someurl.foo** also does the trick