# Will openURL: method of UIApplication will open URL only in safari always?

Tags: ios, safari, uiapplication

I am trying to open a html file from my iPhone/iPad app particularly in Safari. I use openURL method of UIApplication after checking canOpenURL. I doubt if the link will always be opened in Safari. Even in jailbreak iPhones and iPads. If not can I use openFile: withApplication to achieve the same? I referred the stackOverFlow question [Open url in safari through cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745586/open-url-in-safari-through-cocoa-app) .
Is it possible to do without do any scripting bridge mentioned there?
Help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you think that all http or https URLs will be opened in Safari? They will be except for the few documented exceptions.

Comment: it depends on the URL Scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openURL` method will respond on the URL schemes. if it is http, https then it will open in safari.

> differnert URL schemes http, https, tel, facetime, and
>   mailto schemes.

Comment: Even if safari is not the default browser

Comment: Safari is always the default browser in iOS. Are you aware of any way to change that?

Comment: @aparna do you have any case that URL is not open in the safari?

Comment: No. But if we try to jailBreak the iOS, then its possible to change default browser no. Even in that case, I need to open URL in safari. Since I am not the only person who is going to use the app, I cannot make sure that others don't do such jailbreaking process and change default browser. Though the probability of such users are very very low, I just wanted to know if there is some general solution.

Comment: @SunnyShah as of now I dint find any such cases.

Comment: @aparna Ok i will try to find out is there is any case.